# Submit custom data/inputfield while `p:autocomplete` sends a query for fetching suggestions

Tags: jsf, primefaces

How do I submit some `h:inputText` field/send custom data while `p:autocomplete` sends a query for fetching suggestions from server. I tried doing like this:

```
<p:autoComplete completeMethod="..." >
    <p:ajax event="query" onstart="method1()" process="@this, field1"/>
</p:autoComplete>
<h:inputHidden id="field1" value="#{search.value2}"/>
```

The field seems to be submitted along with the sent data to the server however the value is not set in managed bean. Probably the process attribute of above `p:ajax` does not seem to work correctly for above case. So, How do I submit this h:inputHidden#field1 along with query for suggestions ?

Comment: Problem is.. process attribute of p:ajax does not work as expected.. it does not submit the value of field1 in the managed bean.

Comment: Your question says that the data is submitted but not set. Which is it? What's the scope of the backing bean?

Comment: the value of `input#field1` is not set to `#{search.value2}`. The `#{search}` bean is request scoped.

Comment: So, at what point do you need the variable and find out it's not set? Do you get an NPE? The point in the bean's lifecycle at which you're trying to use the value is important, knowing that a request scoped bean is destroyed at the end of every HTTP request

Comment: kolossus, thanks for your responses & help. When a request to fetch suggestions for the primefaces' autocomplete component is sent to server, I want to submit the value of `field1` during that ajax request sent & I'm accessing the expected managed bean property which is expected to(*but does not*) hold the value submitted by `field1` inputText field during the same request stage. Yeah I do get an NPE when I try to access this managed bean property while inside a bean method used as `completeMethod` for `p:autocomplete` component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<p:autoComplete/>`'s `completeMethod` is executed during the `APPLY_REQUEST_VALUES` phase. As you know, in the JSF Lifecycle, request values are not committed to the backing bean model until the `UPDATE_MODEL_VALUES` phase, a full phase *after* the `APPLY_REQUEST_VALUES`.

What this means is that the `completeMethod` cannot access any (new) values that are entered in the view.

To access anything backing bean-dependent, you'll have to do it the hard way, by directly pulling the value off the component:

```
/**
    Find the component
*/
UIViewRoot viewRoot = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot();
UIComponent hiddenInput= viewRoot.findComponent("someId");   

/**
   Get the value
*/
String theValue = hiddenInput.getSubmittedValue().toString();
```