# How to submit additional data to managed bean while p:autocomplete' s completeMethod is triggered for suggestions?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

The title says it all.

--

I'm using primefaces's autocomplete. Whenever a query to server is triggered for fetching suggestions, I need to submit some data from an input field.

How do I do it ?

Comment: You've [asked this exact same question before](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24974781/1530938). Did my answer not work?

Comment: Thanks kolossus! Your answer did worked but I was looking for other elegant solutions to this problem (so that submitted field value is set to managed bean field so that I dont need to dirty my hands with `findComponent().getSUbmittedValue`).

Answer (score 0):

Just add a `keyup` ajax event to the other input, in order to send it when user changes its value. Later on, you'll have it already available for completion:

```
<p:inputText value="#{autoCompleteBean.value}">
    <p:ajax event="keyup" />
</p:inputText>

<p:autoComplete value="#{val2}"
    completeMethod="#{autoCompleteBean.completeItem}" />
```

Comment: the submitted field value is not accessible within `completeMethod`, which is intended.

Comment: My example works and the user input is available in the complete method. What you didn't tell is that you're dealing with a hidden input (BTW, I don't understand why you're resending a value you already have in the bean, is your bean `@RequestScoped`?).

Comment: Oh... does this solution work for `h:inputText` but not for `h:inputHidden`? But why ?

Comment: *I don't understand why you're resending a value you already have in the bean, is your bean @RequestScoped?* -- Yes, bean is request scoped. I'm submitting some data from client to server that is additionally useful for preparing items suggestions for this autocomplete component.

Comment: Then, the answer is simple. Switch to `@ViewScoped` and get rid of the hidden input. That kind of components were widely used in JSF 1.x ages, with the lack of the view scope and the necessity of the state keeping through them. Not anymore.